# Chaotic billiards simulation

Tags: python, math, numpy, physics

I came to ask for some help with maths and programming.

**What am I trying to do?** I'm trying to implement a simulation of a [chaotic billiard system](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dynamical_billiards), following the algorithm [in this excerpt](http://postimg.org/image/yv08iafxh/).

**How am I trying it?** Using numpy and matplotlib, I implemented the following code

```
def boundaryFunction(parameter):
return 1 + 0.1 * np.cos(parameter)

def boundaryDerivative(parameter):
    return -0.1 * np.sin(parameter)

def trajectoryFunction(parameter):
    aux = np.sin(beta - phi) / np.sin(beta - parameter)
    return boundaryFunction(phi) * aux

def difference(parameter):
    return trajectoryFunction(parameter) - boundaryFunction(parameter)

def integrand(parameter):
    rr = boundaryFunction(parameter)
    dd = boundaryDerivative (parameter)
    return np.sqrt(rr ** 2 + dd ** 2)

##### Main #####

length_vals = np.array([], dtype=np.float64)
alpha_vals = np.array([], dtype=np.float64)

# nof initial phi angles, alpha angles, and nof collisions for each.
n_phi, n_alpha, n_cols, count = 10, 10, 10, 0
# Length of the boundary
total_length, err = integrate.quad(integrand, 0, 2 * np.pi)

for phi in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_phi):
    for alpha in np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_alpha):
        for n in np.arange(1, n_cols):

            nu = np.arctan(boundaryFunction(phi) / boundaryDerivative(phi))
            beta = np.pi + phi + alpha - nu

            # Determines next impact coordinate.
            bnds = (0, 2 * np.pi)
            phi_new = optimize.minimize_scalar(difference, bounds=bnds, method='bounded').x

            nu_new =  np.arctan(boundaryFunction(phi_new) / boundaryDerivative(phi_new))
            # Reflection angle with relation to tangent.
            alpha_new = phi_new - phi + nu - nu_new - alpha
            # Arc length for current phi value.
            arc_length, err = integrate.quad(integrand, 0, phi_new)

            # Append values to list
            length_vals = np.append(length_vals, arc_length / total_length)
            alpha_vals = np.append(alpha_vals, alpha)


        count += 1
    print  "{}%" .format(100 * count / (n_phi * n_alpha))
```

**What is the problem?** When calculating *phi_new*, the equation has two solutions (assuming the boundary is convex, which is.) I must enforce that *phi_new* is the solution which is different from *phi*, but I don't know how to do that. Are there more issues with the code?

**What should the output be?** A phase space diagram of S x Alpha, [looking like this](http://postimg.org/image/wp6mgqwqv/).

Any help is very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could try would be (given there really are only two solutions) would be

```
epsilon = 1e-7 # tune this
delta = 1e-4 # tune this
# ...
bnds = (0, 2 * np.pi)
phi_new = optimize.minimize_scalar(difference, bounds=bnds, method='bounded').x
if abs(phi_new - phi) < epsilon:
    bnds_1 = (0, phi - delta)
    phi_new_1 = optimize.minimize_scalar(difference, bounds=bnds_1, method='bounded').x
    bnds_2 = (phi + delta, 2 * np.pi)
    phi_new_2 = optimize.minimize_scalar(difference, bounds=bnds_2, method='bounded').x
    if difference(phi_new_1) < difference(phi_new_2):
        phi_new = phi_new_1
    else:
        phi_new = phi_new_2
```

Alternatively, you could introduce a penalty-term, e.g. `delta*exp(eps/(x-phi)^2)` with appropriate choices of epsilon and delta.

Comment: That's a nice solution. Thank you. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem yet. There must be other mistakes, though I did use the book excerpt's algorithm exactly as it is. Do you see any other possible issues?

Comment: Could you 0. Check with different values of epsilon and delta, 1. post the complete code, 2. tell me what you expect to see versus what you see, 3. output phi_new, phi_new_1 and phi_new_2 please to figure out whether you chose epsilon and delta correctly